# AMD RADEON R5 Series GPU with Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, intel-graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I recently purchased LENOVO IP that comes with integrated GPU INTEL HD620 and dedicated AMD Radeon R5 M430. Now the problem is that ubuntu is only detecting integrated GPU. I want to use AMD GPU.

I know AMD stopped its support for R5 and R7 series GPU. Are there any open source drivers that can support R5 and R7 series GPUs. Basically I want Ubuntu to use my dedicated GPU instead of integrated GPU otherwise there's no point of having a dedicated GPU!

AMDGPU PRO does not support R5 yet. Any other oper source drivers that I can use so that my OS uses dedicated GPU? HELP!

Comment: The open source amd driver is pre-installed, just plug the cable in to the card and start it up. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: AMD supports R5 just fine. It's either radeonsi or r600g *(not sure which one)*. Where did you get that from?

Comment: I read it somewhere. All I want is that my system starts using AMD as its GPU.  For instance when I open 'About This Computer', it shows Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)  on graphics instead of AMD.